# Understanding Character Level Embedding in Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm, embedding, language-model

I am a newbie in implementation of language models in Keras RNN structures. I have a dataset of discrete words (not from a single paragraph) that have the following statistics,

1. Total word samples: 1953
2. Total number of Distinct Characters: 33 (including START,END and *)
3. Maximum length (number of characters) in a word is 10

Now, I want to build a model that will accept a character and predict the next character in the word. I have padded all the words so that they have same length. So my input is Word_input with shape **1953 x 9** and target is **1953 x 9 x 33**. I also want to use Embedding layer. So my network architecture is,

```
    self.wordmodel=Sequential()
    self.wordmodel.add(Embedding(33,embedding_size,input_length=9))
    self.wordmodel.add(LSTM(128, return_sequences=True))
    self.wordmodel.add(TimeDistributed(Dense(33)))
    self.wordmodel.compile(loss='mse',optimizer='rmsprop',metrics=['accuracy'])
```

As an example a word "CAT" with padding represents

Input to Network -- START C A T END * * * * (9 Characters)

Target of the same --- C A T END * * * * *(9 Characters)

So with the `TimeDistributed` output I am measuring the difference of network prediction and target. I have also set the `batch_size` to 1. So that after reading every sample word the network reset its state.

My question is am I doing it conceptually right? Whenever I am running my training the accuracy is stuck about 56%.

Kindly enlighten me. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In my knowledge, the structure is basic and may work to some degree. I have some suggestions

1. In the `TimeDistributed` layer, you should add an activation
   function `softmax` which is wide employed in `multi-classification`.
   And now in your structure, the output is non-limited and it's not
   intuitive as your target is just one-hot.
2. With `softmax` function, you could change the loss to
       `cross-entropy` which increase the probability of correct class and
       decrease the others. It's more appropriate.

you can take a try. For more useful model, you could try following structure which is given in [Pytorch tutorial](http://pytorch.org/tutorials/intermediate/char_rnn_generation_tutorial.html). Thanks.

[image]

Comment: Thank you danche for your quick reply. I had used CCE but missed the softmax. Will try the pytorch tutorial also.